# Google Maps to select cities, countries, states .. etc

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

Is there a way I can have a google maps control on a web page that will allow users to select destinations as a search criteria?

For example we would like a user to be able to select a country, city, state by clicking on it in a map?

Is that even doable?

Comment: I think it will help u ...
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this is absolutely possible.

I am assuming you want to translate the user clicked location into a data structure describing the country, city and state for that position.

To do this you need to use the [reverse geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding). You can add a [click event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/events.html#Event_Listeners) to your google map which gets the latitude and longitude of the location that user clicked:

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, location) {
      // pass the location to the reverse geocoder request
});
```

Once you have the location, you can make a reverse geocode request to get the address.  This address data structure contains the pieces of information (country, city and state) that you are after.  The [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geocoding-reverse.html) in the reverse geocoder service description shows you how to make the request and access the returned data.